# Java Kafka consumer does not resume from where it left

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have producer threads pushing data into a Kafka topic and one consumer thread polling each item at a time. This is the consumer configuration:

```
    private final KafkaConsumer<Long, Integer> consumer;

    public static final String TOPIC = "requestsss";

    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_BROKERS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID_CONFIG);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, MAX_POLL_RECORDS);

        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));

    }
```

And the consumer has the following code running in a loop:

```
  ConsumerRecords<Long, Integer> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10000));
  consumer.commitSync();
  return consumerRecords.records(TOPIC).iterator().next().value();
```

Then the consumer process stops without having consumed all the produced messages. The problem is that when it gets restarted, it does not resume the process from where it left; instead it acts as if all the messages were consumed in the previous run.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I also tried setting

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
```

to both true and false and also removing `consumer.commitSync()` but neither produced the desired effect.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `commitSync` marks all messages received in the last poll as consumed and you return only the first value from the iterator - how do you assume that not all messages were consumed?

Comment: Forgot to mention that MAX_POLL_RECORDS=1

Comment: I know because I'm counting how many messages were produced and how many were consumed. Each poll is retrieving only one message

Comment: yes... you will get only 1 record because you have mentioned MAX_POLL_RECORDS=1

Comment: if the consumer code is running in the loop and is executed multiple times, then MAX_POLL_RECORDS=1 shouldn't be the problem... Two questions: 1. how do you stop the consumption? 2. Is the value in GROUP_ID_CONFIG exactly the same after each restart?

Comment: 1) the thread would simply stop polling records and exit normally, without invoking consumer.close(); 2) yes. Meanwhile I realised that if I perform consumer.close() before exiting it works.

Comment: to read from the beginning of a topic every time it starts: `props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");`